# How to customize the response of the endpoint /oauth/token

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

I am using Spring `Oauth2` support. I have implemented my UserDetails. An example of response from endpoint /oauth/token when the user account is locked is that:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "User account is locked"
}
```

How can override the response? Because I want to receive a numeric key which identifies the error from the server, avoiding to hardcode messages in the cliente side. Something like that:

```
{
"errorCode": "1001"
"error": "invalid_grant"
"error_description": "User account is locked"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These error responses are standard as per the OAuth 2.0 specification. If you are using these standard codes you are not hard coding anything. I am sure all the library authors who adhere to OAuth2 specs will use the same error responses. Here are the standard error responses:

invalid_request, invalid_client, invalid_grant, unauthorized_client, unsupported_grant_type, invalid_scope, error_description, error_uri

Thank you,
Soma